# Developing for ios 6 on Mac OSX 10.5.8

Tags: ios, macos

I am new to ios development and recently acquired a Mac running OSX 10.5.8. I want to develop iPhone apps for the ios 6 SDK. Is this possible on this old version of the Mac OS? If it is possible, what versions of xcode and the sdk do i need to install?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about specific programming question

Comment: "...unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." It seems that SDKs might fall into this category.

Answer (score 2):

you need to update your os OS X lion 10.8.5 and install xcode 5. because xcode 5 only have iOS 7 sdk. if you create new app it must compatible for iOS 7 and support iPhone 5, iPhone 5C

Answer (score 2):

As of February 1, 2014 you should be using latest Xcode 5 and your app must be optimized for iOS7.

Here is the [official statement](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a) from Apple,

> Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be optimized for iOS 7.

In other words, apps developed using older development tools will be **rejected** from the review process.

Xcode 5 minimum OSX requirement is 10.8.4 or later. So you will require to upgrade OSX and development tools.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info - is there a download link for upgrading? I can't figure out how to do it. Every website wants me to buy a dvd with the software on it

Comment: OSX mavericks is available for free on the mac appstore, so is Xcode.

Comment: If i try there it still wants me to buy a dvd, which involves shipping and waiting. I'll pay for the upgrade as long as it's a downloadable file

Comment: @MattMcGrath Hmm .. In your case looks like you may have to buy that DVD. Check this [apple forum discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5534770). Before doing this, please check if your machine meets the minimum requirements for installing OSX upgrades till 10.8.4. Else you may have to buy a new mac.